# Getting apk before uninstalled from devices

Tags: android

I am trying to get apk files before user is going to uninstall but i am getting 0 ResolveInfo
in "arg0.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities( data, 0);"

I think reason is that receiver calls after app uninstalled. I want to know how can i detect the app before uninstallation. so i could copy the apk to sd card before apk uninstall.
My receiver is

```
public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(arg0, "App installing", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();   

    //final Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
    //mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    final List<?> pkgAppsList = arg0.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities( data, 0);
}
```

and receiver in mainfest file is

```
<receiver android:name="com.sparx.androidrecyclebin.Receiver">
    <intent-filter >
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED"/>
        <data android:scheme="package"/>
    </intent-filter>    
</receiver>
```